# Unwanted nested component bug Angular 4 PrimeNg

Tags: angular, primeng

I am currently developing an application with Angular 4 and I have a bug. Indeed, when I change tab or route in my application I have nested components that duplicate. Could someone help me? thank you in advance.

[Please Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMOWl.jpg)

Comment: You aren't going to get much help on this without some code for us to look at.  My suggestions is to fork this http://plnkr.co/edit/6q5v84DWolH6DeAdi70w?p=preview and put your code in there, sharing your new link with us so we can take a look.

Comment: Sorry for late that was a undefined exception